# how to access the child class method using another class in python?

Tags: python, abstract-class, abstract

I have written the code to Abstract Base class, How can i access the child class method (enviorment_trees) using another class? Is it possible?

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod


class EnvironmentAsset(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        print("method1")


class Trap(EnvironmentAsset):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Trap, self).__init__()

    @abstractmethod
    def enviorment_trees(age):
    print("age",age);
    return
```

Comment: This is very unclear. You can't access enviorment_trees at all, because you've marked it as abstract. You can inherit from Trap, override the method, then call super just like any other method though.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure you don't need to mark __init__ as an `abstractmethod` either.